# taskkill to differentiate 2 images by path

Tags: windows, windows-shell

How to kill a process by name and orginiated from a particular path using taskkill?

taskkill /F /IM

certainly it cant differentiate 2 process started from two different locations C:\Dir1 and C:\Dir2

Does tasklist has any switch to get the path name

Answer (score 14):

`taskkill` cannot do it. But you could use PowerShell if it's an option:

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_Process | Where-Object { $_.Path.StartsWith('C:\Dir1') }).Terminate()
```

Comment: For strict equality use `$_.Path -eq "C:\Dir1\file.exe"`. For reference, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-process) is full list of `Win32_Process` class properties.

Answer (score 9):

Use the following command (it works even without powershell):

```
wmic process where ExecutablePath='C:\\Dir1\\image.exe' delete
```

NOTE: ExecutablePath is accessable for all processes only if you run `wmic` as administrator on Windows 8

Comment: Why do I have to use double blackslash? \\

Comment: It doesn't look like a character you have to escape in batch.

Comment: The reason is your using wmic, not batch, even though it is in batch, you are using the command wmic, which does require you to escape it as \ in wmic is different to in batch.

Comment: Genious!! Thanks

Comment: For anyone interested in the NOTE about `wmic` : [windows - wmic process empty executablepath - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63358876/wmic-process-empty-executablepath)

Answer (score 8):

Based on Joey's answer:

```
wmic Path win32_process Where "CommandLine Like '%C:\\Dir1\\image.exe%'" Call Terminate
```

This way I avoid NullReferenceException when Path is null (don't know why) and does not need PowerShell.

Ref: https://superuser.com/questions/52159/kill-a-process-with-a-specific-command-line-from-command-line

---

**Warning**

It is dangerous if there are other processes running with the commandline contains that image path. For example:

```
> start cmd /k "C:\windows\system32\notepad.exe"

> wmic Path win32_process where "CommandLine Like '%C:\\Windows\\system32\\notepad.exe%'" get caption,processid,executablePath,commandline
Caption      CommandLine                                ExecutablePath                   ProcessId
cmd.exe      cmd  /k "C:\windows\system32\notepad.exe"  C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe      11384
notepad.exe  C:\windows\system32\notepad.exe            C:\windows\system32\notepad.exe  9684
```

So... What if we use "C:\Dir1\image.exe%" instead of "%C:\Dir1\image.exe%"?

If we launched this program from Explorer, its commandline *may* be quoted. If we ignore it, there will be no matches:

```
> wmic Path win32_process where "CommandLine Like '%C:\\Windows\\system32\\notepad.exe%'" get caption,processid,executablePath,commandline
Caption      CommandLine                                ExecutablePath                   ProcessId
notepad.exe  "C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe"          C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe  108

> wmic Path win32_process where "CommandLine Like 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\notepad.exe%'" get caption,processid,executablePath,commandline
No Instance(s) Available.
```

Therefore, it is recommended to use "ExecutablePath" like l0pan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13524303/taskkill-to-differentiate-2-images-by-path/23502480#23502480).

Answer (score 4):

Your case seems to be when you have custom services with same process name installed on the machine from different paths. If this is indeed the scenario, you probably have different Service Names which can be used as an additional filter.

See Syntax:

```
taskkill /S {REPLACE_WITH_SERVER_IP_OR_NAME} /F /FI "IMAGENAME eq {REPLACE_WITH_PROCESS_NAME}" /FI "SERVICES eq {REPLACE_WITH_SERVICENAME}"
```

See Example:

```
taskkill /S 10.10.1.1 /F /FI "IMAGENAME eq tomcat7.exe" /FI "SERVICES eq tomcatServiceEngine"
```

For list of all available filters, please visit [taskkill command](https://www.computerhope.com/taskkill.htm)

Answer (score 2):

You can only find **your** processes' path unless you are running powershell with administrator privilege.

32-bit PowerShell cannot find the path of 64-bit process via `Get-Process`, so I suggest you use WMI or CIM. Some references that may be useful:

- [Process Class (System.Diagnostics) | Microsoft Docs § Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process#remarks)
- [c# - How to get the full path of running process? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497064/how-to-get-the-full-path-of-running-process)
- [c - Get command line string of 64-bit process from 32-bit process - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446887/get-command-line-string-of-64-bit-process-from-32-bit-process)

PowerShell way. Based on Joey's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13524303/taskkill-to-differentiate-2-images-by-path#answer-13524338) and user's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13524303/taskkill-to-differentiate-2-images-by-path#comment109236115_13524338).

Assuming that the path of the program is `C:\Dir1\file.exe`. If multiple instances of the program are running, you should use the following command:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Process |
    Where-Object { $_.Path -eq "C:\Dir1\file.exe" } |
        ForEach-Object { $_.Terminate() }
```

Otherwise, Powershell will report an error:

```
PS > (Get-WmiObject Win32_Process |
    Where-Object { $_.Path -eq "C:\Dir1\file.exe" }).Terminate()

Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] doesn't contain a method named 'Terminate'.
```

In addition, the above command also avoids the error when no matching process is found (e.g., the `Path` of no process is equal to `C:\Dir1\file.exe`):

```
PS > (Get-WmiObject Win32_Process |
    Where-Object { $_.Path -eq "C:\Dir1\file.exe" }).Terminate()

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
```

---

If you don't like WMI:

```
Get-Process |
    Where-Object { $_.Path -eq "C:\Dir1\file.exe" } |
        ForEach-Object { Stop-Process -Id $_.Id }
```

---

*I noticed that both [`Win32_Process.Terminate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/terminate-method-in-class-win32-process) and [`Stop-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/stop-process) are used to forcibly terminate the process, so the process may not be able to perform any cleanup work.*

Tested in Powershell 2.0 on Windows 7 (6.1.7600.0).

---

If you do like WMI and you are on Windows 6.2 (Windows server 2012 and Windows 8) and later, you should use `Get-CimInstance` instead of `Get-WmiObject` in PowerShell 3 and later ([Introduction to CIM Cmdlets | PowerShell Team](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/introduction-to-cim-cmdlets/)):

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_Process |
    Where-Object { $_.Path -eq "C:\Dir1\file.exe" } |
        Invoke-CimMethod -MethodName "Terminate"
```

Or, more CIM'y:

```
Get-CimInstance CIM_Process |
    Where-Object { $_.Path -eq "C:\Dir1\file.exe" } |
        Invoke-CimMethod -MethodName "Terminate"
```

Here, you may want to know why `Invoke-CimMethod`:

- [WMI CIM-plified Part 5: WSMAN Protocol -- Microsoft Certified Professional Magazine Online](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2009/05/14/cimplified-part-5.aspx)
- [Hey, Dude! Where Are My Methods? | Scripting Blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/hey-dude-where-are-my-methods/)
- [I’m afraid you can’t do that anymore | Richard Siddaway's Blog](https://richardspowershellblog.wordpress.com/2014/02/27/im-afraid-you-cant-do-that-anymore/)

And, why "CIM":

- [Should I use CIM or WMI with Windows PowerShell? | Scripting Blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/should-i-use-cim-or-wmi-with-windows-powershell/)
- [CIM vs. WMI CmdLets – The top reasons I changed over –
  GivingSomethingBack](https://maikkoster.com/cim-vs-wmi-cmdlets-the-top-reasons-i-changed/)
- [Get-CIMInstance Vs Get-WMIObject: What’s The Difference?](https://blog.ipswitch.com/get-ciminstance-vs-get-wmiobject-whats-the-difference)

I didn't test it on Windows 6.2, but Windows 10 (10.0.19041.0).