# How to kill a process based on its image / file path?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

How to kill a task based on the path of the executable?

The usage of `taskkill /F /IM "app.exe"` doesn't work in this case because there are other programs running that have the same image/process/file name, but are totally different executables. The paths are different and the .exe files with same file name are different, too.

Something like `"taskkill /F /IM "C:\path\to\exe\app.exe"` would be ideal.

Comment: You can use `WMIC` to get that information: `wmic process where "name='myprogram.exe'" get ProcessID, ExecutablePath`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [taskkill to differentiate 2 images by path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13524303/taskkill-to-differentiate-2-images-by-path)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `WMIC`, as suggested in the comments by Squashman, you can do it as a single command:

```bat
WMIC Process Where "ExecutablePath='C:\\path\\to\\exe\\app.exe'" Call Terminate
```