# wmic process empty executablepath

Tags: windows, wmic, taskmanager

Why do some processes from `wmic process get name, commandline, processid, executablePath` not display a value for `ExecutablePath`?

[image: wmic output]

But I can find it in [taskmanager](/questions/tagged/taskmanager)?

[image: taskmgr]

Is there any way to get executable path from [wmic](/questions/tagged/wmic)?

Comment: Some processes simply do not share their path location in WMI. In order to see if there's a workaround for your specific situation, please edit your question to tell us which specific item you're looking for, and what you're trying to achieve once you have done. This site is supposed to provide assistance for a specific reproducible issue with your provided code, please provide that and the other pertinent information, so that we can replicate the issue.

Comment: You are running task manager elevated, but wmic unelevated. Try running wmic elevated.

Comment: wmic.exe can't get the executable path of protected processes (e.g. PsProtectedSignerWindows-Light protection). You can get this information by opening the process with `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` and calling `QueryFullProcessImageNameW`. Note that the discretionary security on the process object may not grant access to administrators (e.g. csrss.exe only grants access to SYSTEM), in which case you can enable SeDebugPrivilege to get limited query access.

Comment: "You are running task manager elevated... " For anyone who wants to know more: 1. [Does task manager run as administrator by default on Windows 10? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1028663/does-task-manager-run-as-administrator-by-default-on-windows-10) 2. [What is the easy way to start Task Manager as an administrator in Windows 8? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/627951/what-is-the-easy-way-to-start-task-manager-as-an-administrator-in-windows-8)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all, especially to @Eryk Sun, here is my quite simple solution for others who will contend with same problem.

`import com.sun.jna.platform;`

```
String getExPath(int pid) {
        Kernel32 kernel32 = Kernel32.INSTANCE;
        WinNT.HANDLE hProcess = kernel32.OpenProcess(WinNT.PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, false, pid);
        char buffer[] = new char[1024];
        IntByReference size = new IntByReference(buffer.length);
        kernel32.QueryFullProcessImageName(hProcess, 0, buffer, size);
        return new String(buffer).trim();
}
```

I was looking for similar method for obtain a commandline of process but i was not sucessfull. I appreciate an advice.