# NtQueryInformationProcess(ProcessBasicInformation) AV for some processes

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

[image: debugger view]
I'm enumerating all processes. As you can see return code is ok, `UniqueProcessId` shows requested process id and `PebBaseAddress` not null, but system throws AV on reading it.

This code works most of the time, but fail for some particular processes (they seem unrelated: `iexplore.exe`, `vcpkgsrv.exe`, `rdpclip.exe`, etc). Win10 22H2

Here is code as text

```cpp
// using PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS nor MAXIMUM_ALLOWED doesn't help
AutoHandleNull hProcess{ ::OpenProcess(ProcessQueryRight/*PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION*/, FALSE, procEntry.th32ProcessID) };
if (hProcess)
{
    ::PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION pbi{};
    ULONG returnLength;
    const NTSTATUS st = pNtQueryInformationProcess(hProcess.get(), ProcessBasicInformation, &pbi, sizeof(pbi), &returnLength);
    if (NT_SUCCESS(st) && pbi.PebBaseAddress && pbi.PebBaseAddress->SessionId == sessionID)
    {
        return procEntry.th32ProcessID;
    }
}
```

Comment: If that process is not your own, you can't read it directly. Use ReadProcessMemory.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError that process is running with the same user in the same session.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError When first writing the code, I actually was wondering how it can return PEB from other process, but there is no need to deallocate memory. Ha-ha. Thanks for hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PebBaseAddress` is in address space of target process, so you need to use `ReadProcessMemory`. Beware that `PEB` contains pointers, so you need check target process mode and use `PEB_X86`/`PEB_X64` accordingly. And if you are in WoW64 process there is some hoop jumps: [Get command line string of 64-bit process from 32-bit process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7446887/5647513)