# x64 modules in a wow64 process?

Tags: windows-7, module, x86, 64-bit, wow64

I have a small 32bit process I'm debugging on win7 x64 and I see that it loads "C:\windows\sysWow64\ntdll.dll" as expected, but also "C:\windows\system32\ntdll.dll"
.
I know that x64 modules and x86 modules do not mix, but here they are... mixing...
How can it be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a special 'feature' of WOW64, see [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384274%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN. the relevant part is:

> The WOW64 emulator runs in user mode. It provides an interface between
> the 32-bit version of Ntdll.dll and the kernel of the processor, and
> it intercepts kernel calls. The WOW64 emulator consists of the
> following DLLs:
>
> - Wow64.dll provides the core emulation infrastructure and the thunks
>   for the Ntoskrnl.exe entry-point functions.
> - Wow64Win.dll provides
>   thunks for the Win32k.sys entry-point functions.
> - Wow64Cpu.dll is an
>   interface library that abstracts characteristics of the host
>   processor. (Intel Itanium only)
> - IA32Exec.bin contains the x86 software
>   emulator. (Intel Itanium only)
> - Wowia32x.dll provides the interface
>   between IA32Exec.bin and WOW64.
>
> **These DLLs, along with the 64-bit
> version of Ntdll.dll, are the only 64-bit binaries that can be loaded
> into a 32-bit process.**