# How can I programmatically retrieve the details of a 64 bit process in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, 32bit-64bit

My goal is to get the full command line of a 64 bit process programmatically. I have understood and written this code where I do a process walk of all the currently running processes and get each of their details. But the issue is that this code fails to do the same for a 64 bit process (one that is not running under WOW64).

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;


BOOL GetProcessList( FILE *f);
BOOL ListProcessModules( DWORD dwPID, FILE *f);
BOOL ListProcessThreads( DWORD dwOwnerPID, FILE *f );
void printError( TCHAR* msg, FILE *f );

typedef BOOL (WINAPI *LPFN_ISWOW64PROCESS) (HANDLE, PBOOL);

LPFN_ISWOW64PROCESS fnIsWow64Process;

BOOL IsWow64(HANDLE processHandle)
{
    BOOL bIsWow64 = FALSE;

    //IsWow64Process is not available on all supported versions of Windows.
    //Use GetModuleHandle to get a handle to the DLL that contains the function
    //and GetProcAddress to get a pointer to the function if available.

    fnIsWow64Process = (LPFN_ISWOW64PROCESS) GetProcAddress(
        GetModuleHandle(TEXT("kernel32")),"IsWow64Process");

    if(fnIsWow64Process != NULL)
    {
        if (!fnIsWow64Process(processHandle, &bIsWow64))
        {
            //handle error
        }
    }
    return bIsWow64;
}


int main( void )
{
    FILE *f = fopen("file_.txt", "w");
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
  GetProcessList(f);
  return 0;
}

BOOL GetProcessList( FILE *f)
{
  HANDLE hProcessSnap;
  HANDLE hProcess;
  PROCESSENTRY32 pe32;
  DWORD dwPriorityClass;


  fprintf(f, "start writing:\n");
  /*
  myfile.open ("example.txt");
  myfile << "writing starts here..." << endl;
  */
  // Take a snapshot of all processes in the system.
  hProcessSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0 );
  if( hProcessSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
  {
    printError( TEXT("CreateToolhelp32Snapshot (of processes)"), f);
    return( FALSE );
  }

  // Set the size of the structure before using it.
  pe32.dwSize = sizeof( PROCESSENTRY32 );

  // Retrieve information about the first process,
  // and exit if unsuccessful
  if( !Process32First( hProcessSnap, &pe32 ) )
  {
    printError( TEXT("Process32First"), f ); // show cause of failure
    CloseHandle( hProcessSnap );          // clean the snapshot object
    return( FALSE );
  }

  // Now walk the snapshot of processes, and
  // display information about each process in turn
  do
  {

    _tprintf( TEXT("\n\n=====================================================" ));
    _tprintf( TEXT("\nPROCESS NAME:  %s"), pe32.szExeFile );
    _tprintf( TEXT("\n-------------------------------------------------------" ));


    fprintf(f, "\n\n=====================================================");
    fprintf(f, "\nPROCESS NAME:  %s", pe32.szExeFile );
    fprintf(f, "\n------------------------------------------------------------");
    /*
    myfile << "\n\n=====================================================";
    myfile << "\nPROCESS NAME " << pe32.szExeFile;
    myfile << "\n-----------------------------------------------------------";
    */
    // Retrieve the priority class.
    dwPriorityClass = 0;
    hProcess = OpenProcess( PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pe32.th32ProcessID );
    //is hProcess the handle to the process?
    if( hProcess == NULL )
      printError( TEXT("OpenProcess"), f );
    else
    {
      if(IsWow64(hProcess)){
        _tprintf(TEXT("\nThe process is running under WOW64.\n"));
        fprintf(f, "\nThe process is running under WOW64.\n");
        //myfile << "\nThe process is running under WOW64.\n";
      }
      else{
        _tprintf(TEXT("\nThe process is not running under WOW64.\n"));
        fprintf(f, "\nThe process is not running under WOW64.\n");
        //myfile << "\nThe process is not running under WOW64.\n";
      }




      dwPriorityClass = GetPriorityClass( hProcess );
      if( !dwPriorityClass )
        printError( TEXT("GetPriorityClass"), f );
      CloseHandle( hProcess );
    }

    _tprintf( TEXT("\n  Process ID        = 0x%08X"), pe32.th32ProcessID );
    _tprintf( TEXT("\n  Thread count      = %d"),   pe32.cntThreads );
    _tprintf( TEXT("\n  Parent process ID = 0x%08X"), pe32.th32ParentProcessID );
    _tprintf( TEXT("\n  Priority base     = %d"), pe32.pcPriClassBase );

    fprintf(f, "\n  Process ID        = 0x%08X", pe32.th32ProcessID);
    fprintf(f, "\n  Thread count      = %d",   pe32.cntThreads );
    fprintf(f, "\n  Parent process ID = 0x%08X", pe32.th32ParentProcessID );
    fprintf(f, "\n  Priority base     = %d", pe32.pcPriClassBase );

    if( dwPriorityClass )
      _tprintf( TEXT("\n  Priority class    = %d"), dwPriorityClass );

    // List the modules and threads associated with this process
    ListProcessModules( pe32.th32ProcessID,f );
    ListProcessThreads( pe32.th32ProcessID,f );
    char *cmd_line = NULL;
    //get_cmdline_from_pid(pe32.th32ProcessID, cmd_line);

  } while( Process32Next( hProcessSnap, &pe32 ) );

  CloseHandle( hProcessSnap );
  return( TRUE );
}


BOOL ListProcessModules( DWORD dwPID,FILE *f )
{
  HANDLE hModuleSnap = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
  MODULEENTRY32 me32;

  // Take a snapshot of all modules in the specified process.
  hModuleSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, dwPID );
  if( hModuleSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
  {
    printError( TEXT("CreateToolhelp32Snapshot (of modules)"), f );
    return( FALSE );
  }

  // Set the size of the structure before using it.
  me32.dwSize = sizeof( MODULEENTRY32 );

  // Retrieve information about the first module,
  // and exit if unsuccessful
  if( !Module32First( hModuleSnap, &me32 ) )
  {
    printError( TEXT("Module32First"), f );  // show cause of failure
    CloseHandle( hModuleSnap );           // clean the snapshot object
    return( FALSE );
  }

  // Now walk the module list of the process,
  // and display information about each module
  do
  {
    _tprintf( TEXT("\n\n     MODULE NAME:     %s"),   me32.szModule );
    _tprintf( TEXT("\n     Executable     = %s"),     me32.szExePath );
    _tprintf( TEXT("\n     Process ID     = 0x%08X"),         me32.th32ProcessID );
    _tprintf( TEXT("\n     Ref count (g)  = 0x%04X"),     me32.GlblcntUsage );
    _tprintf( TEXT("\n     Ref count (p)  = 0x%04X"),     me32.ProccntUsage );
    _tprintf( TEXT("\n     Base address   = 0x%08X"), (DWORD) me32.modBaseAddr );
    _tprintf( TEXT("\n     Base size      = %d"),             me32.modBaseSize );

    fprintf(f, "\n\n     MODULE NAME:     %s",   me32.szModule );
    fprintf(f, "\n     Executable     = %s",     me32.szExePath );
    fprintf(f, "\n     Process ID     = 0x%08X",         me32.th32ProcessID );
    fprintf(f, "\n     Ref count (g)  = 0x%04X",     me32.GlblcntUsage );
    fprintf(f, "\n     Ref count (p)  = 0x%04X",     me32.ProccntUsage );
    fprintf(f, "\n     Base address   = 0x%08X", (DWORD) me32.modBaseAddr );
    fprintf(f, "\n     Base size      = %d",             me32.modBaseSize );

  } while( Module32Next( hModuleSnap, &me32 ) );

  CloseHandle( hModuleSnap );
  return( TRUE );
}

BOOL ListProcessThreads( DWORD dwOwnerPID,FILE *f )
{
  HANDLE hThreadSnap = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
  THREADENTRY32 te32;

  // Take a snapshot of all running threads
  hThreadSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD, 0 );
  if( hThreadSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
    return( FALSE );

  // Fill in the size of the structure before using it.
  te32.dwSize = sizeof(THREADENTRY32);

  // Retrieve information about the first thread,
  // and exit if unsuccessful
  if( !Thread32First( hThreadSnap, &te32 ) )
  {
    printError( TEXT("Thread32First"), f ); // show cause of failure
    CloseHandle( hThreadSnap );          // clean the snapshot object
    return( FALSE );
  }

  // Now walk the thread list of the system,
  // and display information about each thread
  // associated with the specified process
  do
  {
    if( te32.th32OwnerProcessID == dwOwnerPID )
    {
      _tprintf( TEXT("\n\n     THREAD ID      = 0x%08X"), te32.th32ThreadID );
      _tprintf( TEXT("\n     Base priority  = %d"), te32.tpBasePri );
      _tprintf( TEXT("\n     Delta priority = %d"), te32.tpDeltaPri );
      _tprintf( TEXT("\n"));

      fprintf(f, "\n\n     THREAD ID      = 0x%08X", te32.th32ThreadID);
      fprintf(f, "\n     Base priority  = %d", te32.tpBasePri );
      fprintf(f, "\n     Delta priority = %d", te32.tpDeltaPri );
      fprintf(f, "\n");
    }
  } while( Thread32Next(hThreadSnap, &te32 ) );

  CloseHandle( hThreadSnap );
  return( TRUE );
}

void printError( TCHAR* msg, FILE *f )
{
  DWORD eNum;
  TCHAR sysMsg[256];
  TCHAR* p;

  eNum = GetLastError( );
  FormatMessage( FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
         NULL, eNum,
         MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), // Default language
         sysMsg, 256, NULL );

  // Trim the end of the line and terminate it with a null
  p = sysMsg;
  while( ( *p > 31 ) || ( *p == 9 ) )
    ++p;
  do { *p-- = 0; } while( ( p >= sysMsg ) &&
                          ( ( *p == '.' ) || ( *p < 33 ) ) );

  // Display the message
  _tprintf( TEXT("\n  WARNING: %s failed with error %d (%s)"), msg, eNum, sysMsg );
  fprintf(f, "\n WARNING: %s failed with error %d (%s)", msg, eNum, sysMsg);
}
```

It gives me the `ERROR CODE 299`, which indicates that it could not read or write memory from the process, and thus does not provide me the executable command for any 64 bit process.

```
=====================================================
PROCESS NAME:  taskhostex.exe
------------------------------------------------------------
The process is not running under WOW64.

  Process ID        = 0x00001954
  Thread count      = 10
  Parent process ID = 0x000003BC
  Priority base     = 8
 WARNING: CreateToolhelp32Snapshot (of modules) failed with error 299 (Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was completed)
```

Could anyone please help me out with getting around this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible. From the documentation:

> If the specified process is a 64-bit process and the caller is a
>   32-bit process, this function fails and the last error code is
>   ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY (299).

You need to compile your code as 64-bit.

Here more about this issue: [How to enum modules in a 64bit process from a 32bit WOW process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801517/how-to-enum-modules-in-a-64bit-process-from-a-32bit-wow-process).

Comment: +1: Yep, which the error message "The process is not running under WOW64" sort of strongly indicates, to me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Before I accept your answer, as a quick attempt, would you say the same code compiled as 64 bit gives the result?

Comment: Yes, it did. Try it yourself.

Comment: BTW, your code does not work correctly if using the UNICODE character set. You should replace the calls to `fprintf` with `_ftprintf`.

Comment: But when I change it to `_ftprintf`, I get the following error for `_ftprintf(f, "\nPROCESS NAME:  %s", pe32.szExeFile )` - `Trial_1.cpp(99): error C2664: 'fwprintf' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const char [19]' to 'const wchar_t *'`. Anything that's missing or am doing wrong?

Comment: Of course it doesn't work. You need to wrap the strings in the `TEXT` macro. Can't you even copy-paste? You have all you need with the `_tprintf` examples.