# How do I filter a WMI search on what I think is a nested property?

Tags: c#, wmi

I am using the following to get a list of loaded dependents or modules via WMI, but am having issues geting my search string correct, basically I need to target a specific dependent process via its handle, and the handle property seems to be nested inside a `ManagementObject`.

```
var wmiQueryString = string.Format("select * from CIM_ProcessExecutable WHERE Dependent.Handle=\"{0}\"",procID);
using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(string.Format(wmiQueryString)))
using (var results = searcher.Get())
{
    foreach (var item in results.Cast<ManagementObject>())
    {
        try
        {
            var dependent = new ManagementObject((string)item["Dependent"]);
            Console.WriteLine(new FileInfo((string)dependent["Name"]).FullName);
        }
        catch (System.Management.ManagementException ex)
        {
            // Process does not exist anymore
        }
    }
}
```

Using just "Dependent.Handle" does not seem to work, every variation I have tried has resulted in invalid query string exceptions. I assume because the searcher has no understanding of the object structure?

I could load and filter through the data in my C#, but for performance reasons I would like to do the filter in the WMI query.

**Updated code based on answer below:**

```
        var wmiQueryString = string.Format("ASSOCIATORS OF {{Win32_Process.Handle=\"{0}\" }} WHERE ResultClass = CIM_ProcessExecutable", procID);
        using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiQueryString))
        using (var results = searcher.Get())
        {
            foreach (ManagementObject item in results) // This throws System.Management.ManagementException: 'Invalid object path '
            {
                foreach (PropertyData prop in item.Properties) // At this point this is just here for testing, but this is never reached anyway as the exception occurs prior to the iteration.
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", prop.Name, prop.Value);
                }

                //var dependent = item["Dependent"] as ManagementObject;
                //Console.WriteLine(new FileInfo((string)dependent["Name"]).FullName);
            }
        }
```

This however throws `System.Management.ManagementException: 'Invalid object path '` on the indicated line. But this may just be from the previous line, which may still be indicative of a bad query string.

Comment: Don't do the cast at all in the foreach...they're `ManagementObectBase`...and might not be `ManagementObject`. Could be `ManagementClass` instead. Accessing properties are the same either way.

Comment: @clay, even without casting, get the same exception, same line, and i have commented out what is inside the for loop so its the iterator throwing the error.

Comment: Hmmm...we'll get there. Try ResultClass= instead of AssocClass=. There's documentation on Association queries here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384793(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Query for Win32_Process...rather than CIM_Process

Comment: @Clay Those changes result in the same exception still in the foreach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, the secret sauce is `references of` not `associators of`.

```
var wmiQueryString = string.Format( "references of {{win32_process.Handle={0}}}", handle );
using ( var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher( wmiQueryString ) )
using ( var results = searcher.Get( ) )
{
  foreach ( ManagementObject item in results )
  {
    Console.WriteLine( item.ClassPath ); //--> turns out this is the cim_processexecutalbe

    //--> and these are it's properties...with references to cim_datafile...  
    foreach ( PropertyData prop in item.Properties )
    {
      Console.WriteLine( "{0}: {1}", prop.Name, prop.Value );
    }
  }
}
```

This gets you the `CIM_ProcessExecutables` properties:

```
\\CLAYDEV\root\cimv2:Win32_SessionProcess
Antecedent: \\.\root\cimv2:Win32_LogonSession.LogonId="999"
Dependent: \\.\root\cimv2:Win32_Process.Handle="628"
\\CLAYDEV\root\cimv2:Win32_SystemProcesses
GroupComponent: \\CLAYDEV\root\cimv2:Win32_ComputerSystem.Name="CLAYDEV"
PartComponent: \\CLAYDEV\root\cimv2:Win32_Process.Handle="628"
\\CLAYDEV\root\cimv2:CIM_ProcessExecutable
Antecedent: \\CLAYDEV\root\cimv2:CIM_DataFile.Name="C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\winlogon.exe"
BaseAddress: 140696226496512
Dependent: \\CLAYDEV\root\cimv2:Win32_Process.Handle="628"
GlobalProcessCount:
ModuleInstance: 1687814144
ProcessCount: 0
....
```

It also turns out - as Mateo points out in the comments, that `references of` and `associators of` are kinda finicky about formatting. Can't have extra spaces inside the {}. I didn't know that.

You *can* use `associators of`, too. If you get the syntax just so...and you refer to the *associated* type (not the *associating* type). What I mean is `CIM_ProcessExecutables` associates `CIM_Process` to `CIM_DataFile`. So, to get only the `CIM_DataFiles` properties...you can do this:

```
  var wmiQueryString = string.Format( "associators of {{win32_process.Handle={0}}} where resultclass=cim_datafile", handle );
```

...which gets you directly to the CIM_DataFile properties...

```
\\CLAYDEV\root\cimv2:CIM_DataFile
AccessMask: 17957033
Archive: True
Caption: c:\windows\system32\winlogon.exe
Compressed: False
CompressionMethod:
CreationClassName: CIM_LogicalFile
CreationDate: 20170510121417.106825-240
CSCreationClassName: Win32_ComputerSystem
CSName: CLAYDEV
Description: c:\windows\system32\winlogon.exe
Drive: c:
EightDotThreeFileName: c:\windows\system32\winlogon.exe
Encrypted: False
EncryptionMethod:
Extension: exe
FileName: winlogon
FileSize: 707072
FileType: Application
FSCreationClassName: Win32_FileSystem
FSName: NTFS
Hidden: False
InstallDate: 20170510121417.106825-240
InUseCount:
LastAccessed: 20170510121417.106825-240
LastModified: 20170419020715.554583-240
Manufacturer: Microsoft Corporation
Name: c:\windows\system32\winlogon.exe
Path: \windows\system32\
Readable: True
Status: OK
System: False
Version: 10.0.15063.250
Writeable: True
...
```

**Getting only the interesting properties:**

I can't see where there's anyway to select a subset from an `associators of` or `references of` statement...but as suggested in the comments below, you can do a SelectMany to get just the properties you want:

```
  var wmiQueryString = string.Format( "associators of {{win32_process.Handle={0}}} where resultclass=cim_datafile", handle );
  using ( var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher( wmiQueryString ) )
  {
    var results =
      searcher
      .Get( )
      .OfType<ManagementBaseObject>( )
      .SelectMany
      ( df => df.Properties.OfType<PropertyData>( ).Where( pd => pd.Name == "Caption" ) );

    foreach ( PropertyData item in results )
    {
      Console.WriteLine( item.Value );
    }
  }
```

The problem with that is it still iterates the entire property set to get the target property. It seems to run faster to just go straight at the property you want:

```
  var wmiQueryString = string.Format( "associators of {{win32_process.Handle={0}}} where resultclass=cim_datafile", handle );
  using ( var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher( wmiQueryString ) )
  using ( var results = searcher.Get( ) )
  {
    foreach ( ManagementObject item in results )
    {
      Console.WriteLine( item[ "Caption" ] );
    }
  }
```

...but it's not super fast either way, I'm afraid.

Comment: Where does it throw? On this statement?

Comment: On the query string formatter; System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

Comment: Oh - it's the extra {...need to be escaped...will edit

Comment: See if that does the trick...problem with not *testing* the code first

Comment: String format uses `{{`, otherwise looks like the query sting is good now, just need to figure out how to handle the response as my test iterator is throwing System.Management.ManagementException: 'Invalid object path '

Comment: I updated my ? to show my modified code and where the error is throwing.

Comment: @Wobbles - I just rewrote the answer...after playing with it for far too long.  Drove me batsh^t

Comment: @Wobbles You need to remove the space in `\"{0}\" }}` (it should be `\"{0}\"}}`. And as @Clay said you need to use `REFERENCES OF` instead of `ASSOCIATORS OF`

Comment: Lot of good stuff here! Can't wait to shove some coffee down my face and give it a shot!

Comment: @Wobbles - took a stab at it...and it works, but it's still kinda pokey w/o some way to apply a restriction in the actual query - which I can't find a way to do.

Comment: @Clay, I'm having some success using `List<string> managementList = results.Cast<ManagementObject>().Select(m => Path.GetFileName(m["Name"].ToString()).ToLower()).ToList();`, actually for most application it seems to be working fine, there just seems to be a few applications that dont return anything, but I knew this method likely wasnt going to be 100% accurate.

Comment: @Wobbles, I saw in the `CIM_DataFile` results that there are several properties that repeat the full file name...and properties that return the various parts of the full name...which seems (on the surface anyway) wasteful. WMI seems inconsistent in a number of places :-|

Comment: I am also noticing that Process.Modules seems to be inconsistent with the WMI approach in some applications, I may need to use a combination of both, the reason I dont JUST use Process.Modules is my application must be 32bit but I need access to 64bit applications aswell.

Comment: @MatteoUmili Thanks, that turned out to be a *very* helpful observation.